# Web page using media queries for different resolutions

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I am using media queries in this code to create a web page which would look alike for different resolutions. When I try to change the resolution,footer size and header size reduces ( actually half of the content in header and footer is getting cropped) when height of window is resized,footer goes 56px above (i.e) it is not remaining below the web page but it goes 56px up in the content section. I want header and footer look same for all resolutions. Please kindly help me with this.

```
<div data-role="page" id="reader-page" class="bg_main">
    <div data-role="header" id="b_header"> ..... </div>
         <div data-role="content" id="content" class="content_bg"> ...... </div>
         <<div  data-role="footer" id="footer_main">......</div>
</div>

@media screen and (max-width:1440px) and (max-height:900px) {
#b_header{
    background-image: url("../images/titlebar.jpg");    
    height:9.2%;
    }

#footer_main{
    background-image: url('../images/image.jpg');
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:9.2%;            
    }

.bg_main {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%; font-family : calibri;
        color: #544E4F;
        font-size: 1em;
        background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
        font-family: calibri;
    }

.content_bg {
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("../images/bgd_full_screen.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 76.0%;
        width: 100.0%;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one first,

```
<<div  data-role="footer" id="footer_main">......</div>
```

one more < is there.